# How to fool Windows Vista into thinking a USB drive is a fixed drive?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, usb-storage

I have a 3TB USB drive and I want Carbonite to back it up (as it does with my internal hard drives). It will not back up external drives.

I want to trick Windows Vista into reporting this drive (or a mapped directory on the drive) as Fixed.

Any ideas short of Dokan ?

Thanks

P.S. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093785/make-external-drive-to-be-appeared-as-fixed-instead-of-removable-on-windows) thread has not been answered, so please don't send me there

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a symlink or telling windows to mount the drive as a folder in another drive?

Comment: +1 for a symlink.  This is how I get VS to load binaries from a network drive.